# remove data from one list with another list data function not working properly

Tags: java

```
public static void getIndividualsList() {
        List<Employee> individualList = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee individualDtls = new Employee();
        individualDtls.setDependentId(0);
        individualDtls.setDateOfBirth("06/06/1998");
        individualDtls.setEeId(1L);
        individualDtls.setFullName("MICHAEL K HERNANDEZ");
        individualDtls.setCovered(false);
        individualDtls.setDependentType("Self");

        individualList.add(individualDtls);

        List<Employee> individualList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        Employee individualDtls1 = new Employee();

        individualDtls1.setDependentId(0);
        individualDtls1.setDateOfBirth("06/06/1998");
        individualDtls1.setEeId(1L);
        individualDtls1.setFullName("MICHAEL K HERNANDEZ");
        individualDtls1.setCovered(false);
        individualDtls1.setDependentType("Self");

        individualList1.add(individualDtls1);

        individualList.removeAll(individualList1);
        
        for (Employee employee : individualList) {
            System.out.println(employee.getDateOfBirth());
        }
    }
```

Why removeAll is not working properly?

Applied removeAll but still getting data. Can someone please let me know why its not working?

Comment: If you haven't overridden `Employee.equals()`, then Java will default to _identity_ rather than _equality_ when running `.removeAll()`. In which case, despite the two objects being identical, they are in fact not the same object, so they won't compare equal, so it won't get removed. (you can probably have your IDE generate the `.equals()` code for you)

Comment: It is because you are not referencing the same object. Instead you create a new object and try to remove it which does not exist in the list.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy if not possible to add equals and hash code in employee class then what is the other way to do so?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer In the employee class there is restriction. So its not allowing to modify like adding any other methods or comparator. Thats the problem. Thats why trying to find another solution for that

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment: *"In the employee class there is restriction. So its not allowing to modify like adding any other methods or comparator. Thats the problem. Thats why trying to find another solution for that."*

If you have any unique field, maybe you can use that field to iterate over your first list to remove the required items.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      List<Employee> listA = new ArrayList<>();
      listA.add(new Employee("gokul", "1", "gokul@domain.com"));
      listA.add(new Employee("user", "2", "user@domain.com"));
      
      List<Employee> listB = new ArrayList<>();
      listB.add(new Employee("user", "2", "user@domain.com"));
      
      for (Employee eB : listB) {
          for (Employee eA : listA) {
              if (eA.id.equals(eB.id)) {
                  listA.remove(eA);
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      
      for (Employee e : listA) {
          System.out.println(e.name);
      }
    }
    
    static class Employee {
        String name;
        String id;
        String email;
        
        public Employee(String name, String id, String email) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
            this.email = email;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `remove` and `removeAll` relies on `equal` (and `hashCode`!) implementation. Most probably you didn't implement one of this methods.

Without custom implementation of `equal` an object equals only himself. Two variables must reference exactly the same object to be equal. Custom implementation looks like this:

```
class Employee {
    ....
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Employee) {
            Employee oo = (Employee)obj;
            return Objects.equal(fullName, oo.fullName) && Objects.equal(dateOfBirth, oo.dateOfBirth)
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(fullName, dateOfBirth);
    }
}
```

I took `fullName` and `dateOfBirth` to ensure equality. You must manually add all the fields you think important for two objects to be equal (spoiler - it is not trivial).

---

If you cannot modify the object `Employee` there are to ways:

- do it manually as described by "Gokul Nath KP"
- take some other collection structure instead of `ArrayList`. For example `TreeSet` uses an optionally provided custom `Comparator` instance instead of `equal`-Method.